# Auto Populate Slug field django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model defined and over 100+ entries of data in my DB. I would like to auto populate a slug field and see it show up in the admin, since adding new entries for 100+ fields is not something I would like to do.

AutoSlug() field doesnt seem to be working when I add it to my model and make the migrations, `prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('brand_name',)}` does not work using it within my `admin.py` and as well I have tried to add the default field on the slug as my desired field name within the Model but to no avail the solution didnt work.

Is their any other suggestions on how to get the slug filed pre-populated?

```
class Brand(models.Model):

    brand_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100, blank=True, default="", verbose_name=_('Brand Name'))

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Brand Slug'), default=brand_name)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try adding a save method to the Brand class.

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Brand(models.Model):
...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
    super(Brand, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

then run:

```
python manage.py shell

>>>from app.models import Brand
>>>brands = Brands.objects.all()
>>>for brand in brands:
>>>    brand.save()
```

Also, I would change brand_name var to just name.

Comment: note that using bulk_create the model’s save() method will not be called, and the pre_save and post_save signals will not be sent!

Comment: How to access the slug then? its not showing slug filed in the model object.

Comment: correct import is from django.utils.text import slugify

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to add a `pre_save` signal on the `Brand` model.

````
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import signals
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.text import slugify

@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=<model name>)
def populate_slug(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.slug = slugify(instance.brand_name)```
````

Comment: What file is this in? I'm not sure how to use signals, I have tried it before, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an idea, which would do the job, however I am not sure if that would be the best way to do it.

I would use [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) function. I would create the view which - after it was called - would get all model's objects, iterate over them and populate each model's slug field using `django.utils.text.slugify` function with model's `brand_name` as a value.