# How to implement HATEOAS-style links with Django REST framework's ModelViewSets?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this product model

```
import uuid
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    """Product in the store."""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'
```

and I defined a serializer for it

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'price', 'inventory', 'uuid']
```

and this is my view

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import ProductSerializer

from .models import Product


class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
```

To start the question, just keep in mind that this view is routed on `/store/products/`.
Now, for example I can do GET `http://localhost/store/products/` and it returns

```
[
    {
        "title": "Computer",
        "description": "",
        "price": "50.00",
        "inventory": 10,
        "uuid": "2d849f18-7dea-42b9-9dac-2ea8a17444c2"
    }
]
```

but I would like it to return something like

```
[
    {
        "href": "http://localhost/store/products/2d849f18-7dea-42b9-9dac-2ea8a17444c2"
    }
]
```

and then have `http://localhost/store/products/2d849f18-7dea-42b9-9dac-2ea8a17444c2` return

```
{
    "title": "Computer",
    "description": "",
    "price": "50.00",
    "inventory": 10,
    "uuid": "2d849f18-7dea-42b9-9dac-2ea8a17444c2"
}
```

as it already does. Is this possible using the build-in serialization, or how can I define one that does this? I've played around with the `list_serializer_class` property but I can't get anything working.

Comment: Have you seen the documentation on hyperlinked fields?  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield

Comment: @TimNyborg Yes, I spent some time looking at that, but I don't see how it fits in here.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll provide an example below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hyperlinked serializer can return attributes which point to another view, or to another part of the same viewset:

serializers:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    href = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='<app_name>:product-detail', lookup_field='uuid')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['href']

class ProductDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'price', 'inventory', 'uuid']
```

urls:

```py
from rest_framework import routers

app_name ='<app_name>'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products', ProductViewSet, basename='product')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

viewset:

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'uuid'

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = ProductListSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, uuid=None, *args, **kwargs):
        record = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), uuid=uuid)
        serializer = ProductDetailSerializer(record)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Edit: updated to use uuid, not pk, as in your example

Comment: `Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "product-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the 'lookup_field' attribute on this field.`. I was getting this earlier but haven't found a way to fix it.

Comment: That's curious.  It should work so long as lookup_field is the same in your ViewSet and your HyperlinkedIdentityField.  I've cycled through a couple different lookup_fields on a test project, and that error is resolved whenever those two are in sync.

Comment: Oh, I used 'product-detail' because I don't know your url structure.  If you're in a namespace, it may need to be '<namespace>:product-detail'

Comment: It appears the issue is that `ProductListSerializer` is imported before the urlconf is completely loaded, that's why the `product-detail` name is unavailable.

Comment: I mistakenly used self.queryset in  def list and def retrieve, instead of self.get_queryset(), which could prevent it from reinitializing the queryset on each call.  See if that sorts your issue.

Comment: Same thing, here's what I have now https://github.com/2bdkid/storefront/tree/master/store

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235975/discussion-between-tim-nyborg-and-brady-dean).

Answer (score 0):

For URL, you can have **4 options**:

**1-** Use `SlugField` in your model and pre populate it with uuid. You can read about it in [Auto Populate Slug field django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963193/auto-populate-slug-field-django?rq=1)

**2-** Use a `SerializerMethodField` in your serializer and make URL there:

```py
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...
    def get_url(self, obj):
        return self.request.build_absolute_url() + obj.uuid
```

You can read about `SerializerMethodField` in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

**3-** Override `get_absolute_url` in your model and use it in your `SerializerMethodField`. Read about it in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

**4-** Use `HyperlinkedIdentityField` in serializer. docs in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield

---

For detail and list section, use 2 separated serializer, sth like:

```py
class ProductDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'price', 'inventory', 'uuid']

class ProductListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_url(self, obj):
        ...
```

Then, in your `views.py` override `get_serializer_class`:

```py
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    ...
    def get_serializer_class():
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return ProductDetailSerializer
        if self.action == 'list':
            return ProductListSerializer
```